passing an Angular Signal Input value from a service into a component
export class SpecificComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  /** Component configuration object */
  ConfigData = input.required<Config>();
  // some code 
}


Assuming I have Angular components using Signal Input, and I manage
these components in a service as follows:

export class SpecificService {
  private specificComponentRef: ComponentRef<SpecificComponent> | null = null;
 
  SpecificMethod(config: Config) {
    // some code
 
    // Correctly set the value for InputSignal
    this.specificComponentRef.instance.ConfigData.set(config);
 
    // some more code
  }
}


I attempt to set the ConfigData Signal Input like this:

this.specificComponentRef.instance.ConfigData.set(config);


However, I encounter the error: Property 'set' does not exist on type
'InputSignal'.ts(2339). What is the correct way for passing
ConfigData Signal Input value from a service into the component ?


Use a service instead to store the logic

If you have access to ComponentRef you should call setInput.
in your case :
this.specificComponentRef.setInput('ConfigData', whateverValue)


I greatly appreciate your assistance; I have tested it, and it is effective.


I solved this by updating

ConfigData = input.required<Config>();


To

ConfigData = model.required<Config>();


This is really a misuse of a model. model should only be used if you intend to emit events.
